# Problem while updating to macOS High Sierra (Target is not convertible to AFPS)

Tags: macos, encryption, high-sierra, apfs

I started my update at night and woke up in the morning to this screen, stuck at the same place for hours now.

[image]

The error log is a long sequence of the same two lines.

```
isConvertableToAPFS: was called on a APFS disk.
Target is not convertible to APFS: This volume is not formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
```

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

So after browsing around the internet for a bit, I figured there are some solutions I could try.

1. Reboot into internet recovery. [From here.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8084027)
2. Disable encryption. Since in Disk Utility, my drive is shown as Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) and not what you see in the error log.
3. And of course, retry.

But the problem is that I can't afford to lose the data I have downloaded till now, i.e., I can't download 5GB of data all over again.

All the options I see till now, involve closing the the installer. So I have two questions: Will I lose my data if I close the installer? If yes, is there any other to go about it, a fourth option?

My primary aim is not losing data, I plan on keeping the installer running till I don't find a solution.

Comment: Were you ever able to resume the download? Also were you ever able to get past the error: "Target is not convertible to APFS: This volume is not formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled)." ? Best of luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Once I closed it, I had to start all over again.

Answer (score 1):

The installer will still be in your Applications folder. Cancelling should also be fine as the installer automatically backs up your data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Just to be clear, you mean that, even if I close the installer, the next time I open it, I will be resuming from the same point?

Comment: the installer file downloads to your aplications folder . check to see if it is the full 5gb file . I have just just found out that some people are getting a 16mb installer

Comment: sorry i just reread your question you have the full installer

Comment: I don't have the full installer, I have the 16MB one, that's what the screenshot is displaying. I don't have a 5GB file in my applications folder. Previous installations of macOS were downloaded through App Store, so I knew I could resume them. But, if I close this installer, the next time I open it, will I be resuming at the same point?